# Fantasy novel, related to Mesopotamia

Tags: story-identification, novel

I remember not much, and maybe everything is wrong... sorry

- A fantasy novel for youth / young adults
- Modern setting, but ancient Mesopotamia is important
- Archaeology and/or supernatural museum artifacts
- Some kind of portal where something dangerous is
- Protagonists are two adults (1 male, 1 female) and two children
- One of the adults is the parent. The other one is unrelated first, but gets closer until they plan marriage in the end
- Read about 2000-2002, don't know when it was written
- Not part of a series (at least the content didn't seem like there was room to continue)
- The cover of the German version I've seen had some big (dark blue?) spiral as picture

Comment: Can you recall what kind of magic is involved?

Comment: @Adamant Not really, sorry.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Thanks for the edit

Comment: It was a truly minor thing. :)